# Spotfire crosstable conditional formatting

Tags: spotfire

Hi have a very large cross table in spotfire with: 
Sales margins as cell values
Sale reps as vertical
and accounts as horizontal

Can I make spotfire colour code the value based the accounts (horizontal)

This way I would quickly be able to see which sales reps are selling the most on which accounts..

Here an example:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this via color scheme groupings. In the cross table properties, go to colors, and look for the "color by" drop down at the top. You can select any of the columns present on either the horizontal or vertical axis. If you select the [account] column you should then see each account listed under 'numeric' just below. From there you can click each account and set separate color schemes (for example min max gradient coloring evaluated independently for each account).